# Transforming RDD[String] to RDD[myclass]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to transform RDD[String] to RDD[Picture] but could not do it. If I could manage to convert RDD to RDD[Picture] I would use the def hasValidCountry to check if the values latitude and longitude of the picture meta valid. And after that I am trying to check if user Tags are valid with def hasTags in Picture class. The problem I encounter :

1. Implicit conversion found: row ⇒ augmentString(row): scala.collection.immutable.StringOps
2. type mismatch; found : String required: Array[String]
3. value InterestingPics is not a member of Array[Nothing] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value InterestingPics'?

My intention is to choose line which has valid country and tags and transform all the line to new RDD[Picture] class.

ScalaFile1 (I have updated the ScalaFile):

```
  object Part2 {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        var spark: SparkSession = null
        try {
          spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Flickr using dataframes").config("spark.master", "local[*]").getOrCreate()
          val originalFlickrMeta: RDD[String] = spark.sparkContext.textFile("flickrSample.txt")        
          
      val InterestingPics = originalFlickrMeta.map(row => row.split('\t')).map(field => Picture(field(0).toString())
      InterestingPics.collect
      InterestingPics.take(5).foreach(println)
```

Comment: People will find it much easier to answer your question if you follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Your example is not syntactically correct (eg. you're missing 3 closing curly brackets) so your example would produce syntax errors instead of the errors you mention in the post. It's possible your IDE is able to highlight some other errors even if there are syntax problems, but that's not very reliable when the syntax issue affects the scope (eg missing curly brackets), so you really want to fix the syntax first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, as an example:

```
case class case_for_rdd(c1: Int, c2: String, c3: String)

val rdd_data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/csv01-4.txt")
val rdd = rdd_data.map(row => row.split(',')).map(field => case_for_rdd(field(0).toInt, field(1), field(2)))
rdd.collect
```

More complicated example with reading into RDD from file with array. Array needs a delimiter.

```
1,10,100,aa|bb|cc
2,20,200,xxxxxx|yyyyyyyy|z|aaa
```

> Some sample code, but use List as otherwise you get to see `array addresses`, that's what those strange strings are, courtesy of smarter
> people here:

```
case class case_for_rdd(c1: Int, c2: String, c3: String, a4: List[String])  
val rdd_data = spark.sparkContext.textFile("/FileStore/tables/csv03.txt")
val myCaseRdd = rdd_data.map(row => row.split(',')).map(field => case_for_rdd(field(0).toInt, field(1), field(2), (field(3).split("\\|").toList)))
myCaseRdd.collect
```

My advice is to use a DF and the splitting stuff is then easier. Also, manipulation of the `rdd` via transformation, then the `case class` is lost. Array with DF api has no such issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But one thing that i did not understand, my case class Picture have 4 'val' which(lat: double, long: double , c Country, userTags: Array[String]. How it happened that i used input c1: Int, c2: String, c3: String from RDD itself? Also how can i use the two def in the case class which returns boolean values with checking latitude and longtitude.

Comment: An rdd of string means all i string. you then need to do type conversion as I showed on c1, field(0).

Comment: I have updated the question according to your code. But got indexoutofboundexception. RDD string mapped accoording to fields which are defined in the Picture class and we apply in map function. Could not get it how to create a RDD according to my needed values; lat, long ,Country etc. Because the main RDD have n elements in but my intendet RDD will have m elements in which n>m. In this case how spark undertand which field in base RDD will transformed to RDD of Picture Class. I m really confused?

Comment: Trying to read an srray of data from a file? Vsraible or fixed num? Show a snippet of input.

Comment: I shared a snippet of Data. I mean reading line, seperating the line with ',' and writing every element in to Array[String]. But still does not work.

Comment: That is harder with text. The seprator is tab?

Comment: I have updated the code not throwing exception anymore but could not get the proper result.

Comment: I have an swer but I am not happy with it. There is always an issue with textfiles and array elements when not json, etc. Will get back.

Comment: Thank you for your help , but still could not solved the problem.

Comment: I am about to post an update. Will be there soon, but I know this is an odd area. Give me 10.

Comment: Updated the answer. It is not common case class with an RDD.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have an solution to my question in accordence with help of @thebluephantom. Thank you very much.

```
val InterestingPics = originalFlickrMeta.map(line => (new Picture(line.split("\t")))).filter(f => f.c != null && f.userTags.length > 0)
      InterestingPics.collect().foreach(println)
```

Comment: If so, then you could upvote but in the end I think may be a case of lost in translation.